# What's the best way to handle database records with date-type fields?

Tags: karate

When interacting with database records I get LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap objects which I'm struggling to handle properly, especially for date-type fields. Is there a best practice for converting them to standard objects (es. json)?

I've tried using karate.toJson() but I get objects like {} and {"nanos": 904462000}. I tried also the following:

```
* def record = db.readRows('select * from table where condition')
* def res = karate.forEach(record[0], function(x, y){ return { x : y.toString() } })
```

but I get

```
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: null has no such function "toString" in <eval> at line number 1
```

Converting instead each single date-type field with

```
* set record[0].FIELD1 = record[0].FIELD1.toString()
* set record[0].FIELD2 = record[0].FIELD2.toString()
...
```

works fine. I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: read the linked answer please. you are on your own to figure what Java code is being called and what kinds of map objects are being returned. if needed write some extra code to convert them to collections that karate can handle